# Class declaration with a specified base class

Tags: c++, class, declaration

I'm trying to declare class as the following:

```
class MyClass: MyBase;
```

But I can't because compiler is swearing.

```
error: expected ‘{’ before ‘;’ token
```

I'm trying to find a class name declaration to clarify this aspect. But I can't. I'm looking for this in the clause 7 (Declarations) of the c++ working draft.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About standard(n3797):

**9.1 Class names**:

> A class declaration introduces the class name... A declaration
>   consisting solely of class-key identiﬁer; is either a redeclaration of
>   the name in the current scope or a forward declaration of the
>   identiﬁer as a class name. It introduces the class name into the
>   current scope.

**10 Derived classes**:

> A list of base classes can be speciﬁed in a class **deﬁnition**...

So, you can just tell the compiler: "Oh, I will define this class later". If you need to know the "structure" of the class then you need to define it.

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to *declare* the `MyClass` class, then

```
class MyClass;
```

is enough. It tells the compiler that the class `MyClass` exists, and you can now declare pointers or references to `MyClass`.

If you want to *define* the class, then you need to full definition.

Answer (score 1):

Give definition in this way :

> class MyClass: MyBase
>
> {
>
> //////
>
> };

If you only want to declare then do in this way :

> class MyClass;